# Nested IF Function with Multiple Conditions - either returns False or Value#

Tags: excel-formula

Was trying to create a formula for a team scorecard.

Was trying to refer to different columns such that if an agent belongs to `Email`, and is tagged `Qualified`, he gets to receive following payout:

KRA Score of:

- 1 = Php0
- 2 = Php0
- 3 = Php1,000
- 4 = Php3,000
- 5 = Php5,000

However, if Agent is from `Voice` and is qualified, he/she receives different amount as follows:

KRA Score of:

- 1 = Php0
- 2 = Php0
- 3 = Php2,000
- 4 = Php4,000
- 5 = Php6,000

Here's my sample data and corresponding payout amount same as above:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do no, I repeat - do not use nested `IF`s - they are evil.  They are difficult to write and impossible to maintain.  `VLOOKUP` is only marginally better, it's a chaotic neutral.  What you should do instead is to invest some of your time into learning about array formulas, named ranges/tables and `INDEX`/`MATCH` functions.  There are many on-line tutorials, just Google them.

[image]

`=INDEX(Payouts[#All],
MATCH([@Score],Payouts[[#All],[Score]],0),
MATCH([@Group],Payouts[#Headers],0))`

Just add `IF` in front of the formula:

[image]

Comment: Hello Michal - much appreciated the response. Can we also take into consideration the condition Qualified/Disqualified as we will only payout of Qualified agents? It is possible that an agent may receive a rating of 3,4,5 but is disqualified due to a gatekeeper we set (in this case, attendance score of >=95% plus KRA Rating of >=3 determines if an agent is qualified), hence should not receive a payout if tagging in Column D is disqualified (regardless if KRA Score is 3,4 or 5.

Comment: Please see above

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following formula to be entered into cell `E2`:

```
=IF($D2="Qualified",VLOOKUP($C2,$A$13:$C$17,IF($B2="Email",3,2),FALSE),0)
```

[image]

Here, the outermost `IF` statement checks whether the Agent is `Qualified`. If the Agent is `Disqualified`, the formula returns `0`.

If so, the `VLOOKUP` looks up the `Score` from the range of scores & payouts (assuming these appear in the range `$A$13:$C$17`), and returns either column `3` if the Agent belongs to `Email`, else column `2`.

The fourth argument (`FALSE`) supplied to the `VLOOKUP` function ensures that the score must appear in the supplied range for a payout to be returned. If the score is not present, the `VLOOKUP` will return `N/A`.

You could account for this by enclosing the `VLOOKUP` with the `IFERROR` function to return a predetermined value if the score is not found.

Comment: Hello, this did the trick! :) I am also going to start learning INDEX and MATCH as advised by Michal Rosa!

Comment: @Enthusiast_AO You're welcome! Please mark my answer as the solution if it answers your question, so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site, thanks.